# Ethernet on my Mac mini M1 going on and off

Tags: network, wifi, mac-mini, ethernet

I've got a Mac mini M1 connected to the LAN through a switch. I've got also a Windows PC on that switch and the network works fine, but the Mac's Ethernet connection goes on and off constantly.

I've tried to apply the solution [published on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434001/m1-mac-mini-loses-ethernet-connection-frequently), but it doesn't work for me. The problem persists even if I change IPv6 settings or create different locations. I can connect to the WiFi and work, but I'd like to be able to enjoy my ethernet network as well. [I've created a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfdNwWsrYLE) with the connection going on and off on the settings window on macOS.

Comment: A network switch - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch